# Unable to delete node in firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

I am having trouble deleting a node in firebase using javascript. The structure of my database is this:

```
Users
    -khdlahdjhaldjsh
          email: "dasdad"
          phone: "1223123"
     -kjadkjskjadlsjkd
```

And I am deleting a node by doing this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
ref.child(child_key).remove(function(error) {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log("success"); 
            }
        });
```

Where child_key corresponds to ids like -khdlahdjhaldjsh.

There is no error but the node is not deleted. I have seen other examples where this seems to work.